Angular: registering providers from library using standalone approach
I have bootstrapped an Angular v18 workspace with an application and a library. I've created a service in the library and wanted to use that in the application. Everything organized with the standalone approach, without NgModules.
Previously I've registered the providers in the library's NgModule and was importing it in the application with the module's forRoot(...) method. How can I achieve the same without NgModules (using the standalone approach)?

You have to use importProvidersFrom to add them to the providers array of bootstrapApplication.
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

...
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom([
       ...
       YourModule.forRoot(),
       ...
    ]),
  ]
});


Yeah, but this assumes that providers in the library are organized to a NgModule and use them by calling the .forRoot() method. Is the same result reachable without NgModule?

@MiklósSzabó do you mean it's standalone? which library, could you give a reference. You could try adding the services directly to the providers array, of either bootstrapApplication or AppComponent
